# How to use i18n key as default translation in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

For example:

```
I18n.t('something')
```

should output only

```
something
```

if the translation missing.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

nope, not possible. If you use I18 you need to have a file that corresponds to the language otherwise I18n will complain.

Of course you can set the default language in your environment.rb file. Should be near the bottom and you can set this for whatever language you want but in your `locales/` folder you will need to have a corresponding `yml` translation.

Answer (score 25):

It is possible:
See section *4.1.2 Defaults* at [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations).

```
I18n.t :missing, :default => 'Not here'
# => 'Not here'
```

Answer (score 7):

On rails 4 you can change the exception handler.

Add the following to `config/initializers/i18n.rb`:

```
module I18n
  class MissingTranslationExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslation)
        key
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::MissingTranslationExceptionHandler.new
```

Now on you views you can just do:

```
<p><%= t "Not translated!" %></p>
```

Guide on the subject: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers

Comment: One might want this only for a specific environment only. Adding this as an initializer limits possibilities. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

side-note:
this might help figuring out what Rails thinks the current scope is (e.g. when using ".something")

http://unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/which_l10n_strings_is_rails_trying_to_lookup.html

this way you can better avoid having missing translations because of incorrect placing of translations strings in the L10n-file / incorrect keys

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is the right solution to the question, another (more verbose) way to do it is to rescue and return the key:

```
def translate_nicely(key)
  begin
    I18n.translate!(key)
  rescue
    key
  end
end
```

Comment: Using exception logic for conditional flow is generally bad practice. From the Refactoring book: http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceExceptionWithTest.html

Comment: I'd agree that it's generally bad practice, I've also made a point of saying David's solution is the correct way to fall back to a default value. Of course there are also (pragmatic) cases where you do not want the application to expose an error and use a sensible default to provide a better user experience. I'd say it's fair to stray from the guidelines and handle errors nicely when this is the case.